# Simple code to print number of red or green candlesticks per distance in MetaEditor?

Tags: function, forex, mql, candlesticks

I am trying to do this.

1. Download or scan candlesticks chart of a currency pair.
2. Write simple code in MetaEditor to count the number of red and green candlesticks per increase in time.
3. Save the progressive numbers to a text file.

For instance I counted it manually on the monthly timeframe for EURUSD and it ends something like this.

Starting from red. 114422321141414412122.

In case you still don't get me. Here's what I mean. If the price moves, starting from red, 4 candles down, 4 candles up, 2 candles down and 2 candles up, and 3 candles down. Then reading on my possible text file is 44223. Or even R4G4R2G2R3.

Please help. I am new to coding in MetaEditor but I know C programming language.